# How to rotate a single page to landscape in R Markdown pdf output

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, landscape

I'm new to R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would like to rotate a single page to landscape in R markdown (pdf).

In the YAML header I have added the following (based on a previous post):

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output: pdf_document
```

and then:

```
\blandscape
```

where I wish to change to landscape (is it correct that this should not be added to the code chunk?).

However I get an error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{landscape} on input line 193 ended by \end{document}.
```

This is probably a stupid question but do I need to download this package pdflscape? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also end your landscape page with `\elandscape` like this:

````
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

\blandscape

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.

\elandscape
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: This rotates the page number to the left side, is there a way to fix this?